# Programmatically add VBA project references without VBE or VBIDE..?

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

This is a different twist to the old question about programmatically adding VBA project references: is there a way to programmatically add references, but...*without VBE or an existing reference to VBIDE*..?

Many Microsoft apps have the built-in application class `VBE`, with its own references collection: `Application.VBE.ActiveVBProject.References`. This includes Access, Excel, Word, PowerPoint, Visio, and probably many others. But some Microsoft apps don't have VBE, such as Outlook and Publisher. Plus, there are a variety of 3rd-party software packages with VBA, such as AutoCad and Corel Draw, but whether these have the VBE class is not known.

For those apps that don't have VBE, is there any fully-programmatic way to add a reference to VBIDE..? (assuming it's on the system)

I'm willing to entertain just about any idea except `SendKeys`. I've had thoughts of editing the document files at the character level. For instance, I'm sure if I drill down into the XML of an Excel file, I'd find the tags where the VBA references are stored. And for Access it would be SaveToText and LoadFromText, then dig through the text file. But for other apps, I know nothing or next to nothing of their file structures.

Comment: Pretty sure that would be a security hole.. Programmatic access to the VBIDE Extensibility library needs to be explicitly enabled... at least in Office.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Also.. Outlook *is* a VBE host app. OneNote isn't.

Comment: You can tweak VBA project references... if you're a VBIDE add-in. If you're a VBA project, tough luck.

Comment: I suggest that you consider using late binding instead. This will solve the problems you might encounter with references for much less effort.

Comment: @this Note that you can't do everything with late binding. Specifically, you can't use events on late bound objects. For cases where those aren't needed, I agree with you, though

Comment: << I'm sure if I drill down into the XML of an Excel file, I'd find the tags where the VBA references are stored>> Probably not. The VBA code is stored in *binary* file format within the Office Open XML zip packages.

Comment: To answer all these comments: § I forgot about that little tidbit of enabling VBIDE in the security center; I've had it enabled for so long that I forgot about it. § I would like to start sharing code that works without needing the user to add references, like RegEx, Scripting, or automating Excel from Access. § I Haven't start exploring Add-Ins; it's on my list. § I can't find VBE or 'References' in Outlook in the Object Browser. § I dislike late-binding because Intellisense doesn't work. But, I suppose I could change before sharing it. § I thought perhaps the references might not be binary.

Comment: And now that I'm thinking this through a bit more from a security standpoint, I'm realizing anything sneaky I try to do to make it work would probably set off alarm bells in the AV software, because that's what a hacker would do. I guess I'll just have to develop early bound first, then convert to late-bound when I share, and add the usual notes/instructions about adding Reference X.

Answer (score 2):

Mathieu Guindon is right, VBA needs access granted to manipulate workbook projects, typically one grants this once for an installation and it rarely gets revoked.   Cindy Meister is right the references are stored in the binary blob so drilling into the xml will not help.

To grant access, (this is on Excel 2016)

- Click on File then on menu which flies in from left select Options, this displays Excel Options dialog.
- On Excel Options dialog, on the left hand menu select Trust Center, this displays Trust Center pane.
- In Trust Center pane, click Trust Center Settings, this display a Trust Center dialog.
- in the Trust Center dialog, on the left hand menu, select Macro Settings ...
- In the Macro Settings pane, check the checkbox "Trust access to the VBA project object model"

So the following code works for me because access is granted.    The code adds the Microsoft Scripting Runtime library (that is my favourite non-core).

```
Sub Test()

    Dim objProj As Object 'VBIDE.VBProject
    Set objProj = ThisWorkbook.VBProject

    Dim vRefLoop As Variant

    Dim bIsMyReferencePresent As Boolean
    bIsMyReferencePresent = False
    For Each vRefLoop In objProj.References

        Debug.Print vRefLoop.Name
        If vRefLoop.Name = "Scripting" Then

            bIsMyReferencePresent = True

        End If

    Next

    If bIsMyReferencePresent = False Then

        objProj.References.AddFromFile "c:\windows\syswow64\scrrun.dll"

    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Yes, I'm familiar with it. Coding VBA in Access and Excel is a major chunk of my day at work. I regularly have to enable macros and VBIDE when I give something to a user that hasn't enabled it before. I hadn't considered all these security issues, and the major holes that would be created by what I'm asking about. Document files from a host integrated with VBA are a huge security risk. I've read the Chip Pearson comments about AV scanners that summarily delete any references and code to do with VBIDE. Unpleasant for the developer. But it  makes sense. This is why we can't have nice things.

Comment: Oh, ok, I see the problem with AV scanners.  Erm, as part of your solution perhaps ship a template with all the references already there so no need for VBIDE.

Comment: What is the library you want to add?  Is it another workbook?

Comment: No; this is in Access, to automate the use of SQL data to create Excel workbooks with complex formatting, and then to email them, with plans to expand it with a scheduling system. Think of it as a more complex & versatile version of the Access data export feature. Aside from the basic four references that every Office app has, this project has nine additional ones. Here's a list: Excel, Graph, Scripting, VBScript_RegExp_55, VBIDE, Office, MSACAL, MSComCtl2, and MSForms.

Comment: then ship an Excel template (*.xltm) with all of those perhaps?

Comment: Not applicable to what I was hoping for. I have a lot of weird code that I develop. My job is low-pressure, so I have time & latitude to do experimental and creative coding. I'm going to create a web page to start sharing my code, especially some of the quirkier things I've discovered. I wanted to include a function to automatically add the appropriate references, of which VBIDE is important because it gives access to the References() collection for VBA-integrated apps without a VBE object. But VBE will suffice for those apps that have it.

Answer (score 0):

Your idea is very interesting:

> I've had thoughts of editing the document files at the character
>   level. For instance, I'm sure if I drill down into the XML of an Excel
>   file

The references are not saved in an XML but rather in `./vbaProject.bin` (for Excel vers. >5) in the .xlsm file which is just zip archive. This `vbaProject.bin` is a binary blob within the zip archive, but there have been attempts to decode it, e.g. in the **officeparser** project there is [some code](https://github.com/unixfreak0037/officeparser/blob/master/officeparser.py#L973) to detect the array of VBA references.
Using this code it should be possible to engineer an update function for this array.